# access denied doesn't work symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a small problem on the redirection when the access of the page is refused to the user when the latter does not have the right role.

Instead of being redirected to the index, it is redirected to the login page, although in my code I put: access_denied_url: /

For example I try to access the next page with the wrong role:
- {path: ^/dashboard, role: ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN}

I would like him to redirect me to the index, instead of the login page

My security.yml:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
                # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
                security:
                    access_denied_url: /
                    role_hierarchy:
                        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
                        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
                        SONATA:
                            - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT  # if you are using acl then this line must be commented

                    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
                    providers:
                        in_memory:
                            memory: ~

                        fos_userbundle:
                            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

                    firewalls:
                        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
                        dev:
                            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                            security: false

                        admin:
                            pattern:      ^/
                            form_login:
                                provider:       fos_userbundle
                                login_path:     /login
                                use_forward:    false
                                check_path:     /login_check
                                failure_path:   /login
                                default_target_path: /dashboard
                                remember_me: false 
                            logout:
                                path:           /logout
                                target:         /
                                invalidate_session: true # the authenticated session will be unavailable afterwards
                            anonymous:    true

                    encoders:
                        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

                    acl:
                        connection: default

                    access_control:
                        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
                        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
                        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
                        - { path: ^/admin/*, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
                        - { path: ^/admin/dashboard, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
                        - { path: ^/dashboard, role: ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN }
```

My rounting.yml :

```
mybundle:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix:   /

#app:
 #   resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
 #   type: annotation

admin_area:
    resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user_security:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_security_1.xml"

sonata_user_resetting:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_resetting_1.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

sonata_user_profile:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_profile_1.xml"
    prefix: /profile

sonata_user_register:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_registration_1.xml"
    prefix: /register

sonata_user_change_password:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_change_password_1.xml"
    prefix: /profile

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user_admin_security:
   resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
   prefix: /admin

sonata_user_admin_resetting:
   resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_resetting.xml'
   prefix: /admin/resetting

fos_user_group:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/group.xml"
    prefix: /group
```

Thank you

Comment: May be you are not authenticated... Check your logs for records with "An AuthenticationException was thrown" or "Access denied"

Comment: Actually, I can not log in because I do not have access rights to this page. And I would like him to redirect me to the index and not the login page when I do not have the right role

Comment: How do you want to redirect to the index page if you can't even log in?